# Test for differences in distribution without raw data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, genetics

I've got a series of statistics computed on different populations of cells, where each population contains a different genetic deletion. 
The measurements I have for each population involve GFP intensity: median intensity, mean intensity, median absolute deviation of intensity, max intensity and min intensity.
I'd like to test whether the distributions are significantly different between each  mutant strain and a wild type (no mutation) strain, but I don't have any access to the raw data from which these statistics were calculated.
Can anyone tell me if there are tests like Wilcoxon / Mann-Whitney (or even the Kolmogorov-Smirnov) that function on statistics rather than raw-data?  Or could someone suggest an alternative?

Comment: It might help if you knew what kind of distribution "GFP intensity" ([Green Fluorescent Protein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_fluorescent_protein)?) typically has.

Comment: @Henry: the intensity distributions are continuous and non-negative.  I'm guessing that for a given population of cells, GFP intensity could be reasonably well approximated by a gamma distribution

Comment: Do you know the sample sizes?  If so it should be possible.

Comment: @PeterEllis: I do know the sample sizes.  Could you suggest some reading for me?